# Would it make sense to merge (and possibly establish a synonym) for ubuntu-on-arm to arm?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I noticed that the main site tag for [ubuntu-on-arm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-arm) is being used in the exact same manner as the [arm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/arm) tag and wondered if there were a reason why they weren't merged?

- 16 posts (12 this year) - https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-arm
- 111 posts (61 this year) - https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/arm

Answer (score 1):

No. ARM is a cpu architecture, ubuntu-on-arm is a distribution of ubuntu made specifically for arm. We don't take ARM (the CPU architecture) related questions but we take Ubuntu running on ARM questions. ARM should be removed and questions retagged to ubuntu-on-arm where applicable.

There are couple of questions about installing ARM related tools, those should have the software installation tag. If you want to ask about installing Ubuntu on ARM architecture, it should have the system installation tag.

Comment: I took the ARM wiki description at face value "Questions relating to the use of ARM microchip architecture with Ubuntu" I'm not sure what you are saying - are you calling to move all the existing questions to the longer tag?

Comment: Well, the problem is that is potentially misused. To put a popular example, [How can I install Ubuntu on an iPad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6263/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-ipad) used this tag. AMR tag doesn't help me to identify what the question is about if I don't read the title. There are other questions about the AMR toolchain, etc. I'm taking the misuse as face value of the tag. When asking about merging/synonymizing tags, you must make sure that both tags are about the same topic in name and in reality.